# What's the "right way" to restart services in 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, networking, wireless, init.d

I have a stack of things I used to do when my wireless was spazzing out (which it seems to do from time to time), including running `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` but lately I'm getting this when I run it:

> *Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces`

So ... what am I supposed to do instead?